# Sum specific cells up to a certain value and then multiply the remaining ones

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a code to add specific hours cells until I reach "HorasE" in this case the limit is 45. If the sum is reached from 45 it is subtracted 45 and the remaining is multiplied by 1.5, then the remaining cells multiply individually by 1.5 but round to the nearest .5. Then everything adds up to 45 and the multiplications of the rest. In case of not exceeding 45 simply a normal sum is made. The code I made is as follows, but I think it is very poorly organized and not very simplified, but it works.

```
 With Sheets("Llenado")
        Set J = .Range("D11")
        Set V = .Range("F11")
        Set S = .Range("H11")
        Set L = .Range("L11")
        Set M = .Range("N11")
        Set Mi = .Range("P11")
        Set J2 = .Range("D14")
        Set V2 = .Range("F14")
        Set S2 = .Range("H14")
        Set L2 = .Range("L14")
        Set M2 = .Range("N14")
        Set Mi2 = .Range("P14")
        Set D = .Range("J11")
        Set D2 = .Range("J14")
    End With

    HorasE = Sheets("Llenado").Range("D7")

    If Sheets("Llenado").Range("B6").Value = "Si" Then
        If J.Value + V.Value + S.Value + L.Value + M.Value + Mi.Value > HorasE Then
            Extras = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(J.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(V.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(S.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(L.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(M.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Mi.Value, 0.5) - HorasE
            Extras = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Extras * 1.5, 0.5) + HorasE
            Extras2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(J2.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(V2.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(S2.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(L2.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(M2.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Mi2.Value * 1.5, 0.5)
            Extras3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(D.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(D2.Value * 1.5, 0.5)
            Sheets("Llenado").Range("Q10").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Extras + Extras2 + Extras3, 0.5)
        Else
            If J.Value + V.Value + S.Value + L.Value + M.Value + Mi.Value + J2.Value > HorasE Then
                Extras = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(J.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(V.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(S.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(L.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(M.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Mi.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(J2.Value, 0.5) - HorasE
                Extras = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Extras * 1.5, 0.5) + HorasE
                Extras2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(V2.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(S2.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(L2.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(M2.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Mi2.Value * 1.5, 0.5)
                Extras3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(D.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(D2.Value * 1.5, 0.5)
                Sheets("Llenado").Range("Q10").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Extras + Extras2 + Extras3, 0.5)
            Else
                If J.Value + V.Value + S.Value + L.Value + M.Value + Mi.Value + J2.Value + V2.Value > HorasE Then
                    Extras = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(J.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(V.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(S.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(L.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(M.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Mi.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(J2.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(V2.Value, 0.5) - HorasE
                    Extras = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Extras * 1.5, 0.5) + HorasE
                    Extras2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(S2.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(L2.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(M2.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Mi2.Value * 1.5, 0.5)
                    Extras3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(D.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(D2.Value * 1.5, 0.5)
                    Sheets("Llenado").Range("Q10").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Extras + Extras2 + Extras3, 0.5)
                Else
                    If J.Value + V.Value + S.Value + L.Value + M.Value + Mi.Value + J2.Value + V2.Value + S2.Value > HorasE Then
                        Extras = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(J.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(V.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(S.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(L.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(M.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Mi.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(J2.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(V2.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(S2.Value, 0.5) - HorasE
                        Extras = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Extras * 1.5, 0.5) + HorasE
                        Extras2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(L2.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(M2.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Mi2.Value * 1.5, 0.5)
                        Extras3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(D.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(D2.Value * 1.5, 0.5)
                        Sheets("Llenado").Range("Q10").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Extras + Extras2 + Extras3, 0.5)
                    Else
                        If J.Value + V.Value + S.Value + L.Value + M.Value + Mi.Value + J2.Value + V2.Value + S2.Value + L2.Value > HorasE Then
                            Extras = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(J.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(V.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(S.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(L.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(M.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Mi.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(J2.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(V2.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(S2.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(L2.Value, 0.5) - HorasE
                            Extras = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Extras * 1.5, 0.5) + HorasE
                            Extras2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(M2.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Mi2.Value * 1.5, 0.5)
                            Extras3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(D.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(D2.Value * 1.5, 0.5)
                            Sheets("Llenado").Range("Q10").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Extras + Extras2 + Extras3, 0.5)
                        Else
                            If J.Value + V.Value + S.Value + L.Value + M.Value + Mi.Value + J2.Value + V2.Value + S2.Value + L2.Value + M2.Value > HorasE Then
                                Extras = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(J.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(V.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(S.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(L.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(M.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Mi.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(J2.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(V2.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(S2.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(L2.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(M2.Value, 0.5) - HorasE
                                Extras = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Extras * 1.5, 0.5) + HorasE
                                Extras2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Mi2.Value * 1.5, 0.5)
                                Extras3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(D.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(D2.Value * 1.5, 0.5)
                                Sheets("Llenado").Range("Q10").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Extras + Extras2 + Extras3, 0.5)
                            Else
                                If J.Value + V.Value + S.Value + L.Value + M.Value + Mi.Value + J2.Value + V2.Value + S2.Value + L2.Value + M2.Value + Mi2.Value > HorasE Then
                                    Extras = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(J.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(V.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(S.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(L.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(M.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Mi.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(J2.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(V2.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(S2.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(L2.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(M2.Value, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Mi2.Value, 0.5) - HorasE
                                    Extras = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Extras * 1.5, 0.5) + HorasE
                                    Extras3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(D.Value * 1.5, 0.5) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(D2.Value * 1.5, 0.5)
                                    Sheets("Llenado").Range("Q10").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Extras + Extras3, 0.5)
                                Else
```

[image]

Comment: And the question is? Perhaps upload into Google Sheets and link it. Then tabulate in your question what you are looking to see, explaining why.

Comment: You explain pretty well what you would like to achieve with your code. In the end you state that the code works, so what's the question?

Comment: Sorry, my question was whether there is any more efficient or more summarized code.

Comment: Better post it in [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and remember to post the complete code

Comment: My bad, Thank you :)